# How to make a jpeg formatted image using PHP?

Tags: php

Here is my current code:

```
.
.
.

ob_start (); 
imagepng($im, null, 9, PNG_ALL_FILTERS);
$image_data = ob_get_contents (); 
ob_end_clean (); 
echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode ($image_data) . "' />";
```

The output is a .png image which looks right. Now I want to make it this way:

```
.
.
.

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

But in this case, the image won't be created. The result will be a black page:

[image]

Any idea what's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: what does the `...` signify, exactly?

Comment: @RamRaider [full code](https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/396e2579b12525c4619d66d72ce5d1fa)

Comment: @SeanBright Nothing changed .. still the same black page.